# Swift 3- How to get button in UICollectionViewCell work

Tags: ios, swift, material-design

I am trying to implement an Edit button inside a cell.

Please refer to image:
[image]

What I done so far:

MainController:

```
class MainController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout  {
  let imgCellId = "imgCellId"

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView?.register(ImgItemCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: imgCellId)
  }

  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {   
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: imgCellId, for: indexPath) as! ImgItemCell
      cell.editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

      return cell
  }

  func buttonPressed(){
    print("buttonPressed !")
  }

}
```

ImgItemCell:

```
import Material

class ImgItemCell: UICollectionViewCell{

   override init(frame: CGRect){
       super.init(frame: frame)

       setupViews()
   }
   ...
   let editButton: RaisedButton = {
       let button = RaisedButton(title: "Edit", titleColor: .black) return button
   }()

  func setupViews(){
     ...
     addSubview(editButton)
     ...
  }

}
```

**Result:** The button is not clickable. No log is printed when clicking on the button.

In android, I have done this by `OnClickListener` of button to perform action for each row. How can I do the same in Swift 3?

**Solution:** (it's working for me)

Hi all thank you for all suggestions, they’re more less the hint for me to come to the solution.

The root cause of my problem is view hierarchy (as @DatForis pointed out)

Explanation: I want a cell contains image and a layout of buttons so that I had view hierarchy as below

```
override func setupViews() {
    super.setupViews()

    addSubview(imgView)
    addSubview(buttonLayout)
    buttonLayout.addSubView(buttonList)
            buttonList.addSubview(editButton)
            buttonList.addSubview(shareButton)
  }
```

this hierarchy somehow blocked the click event of button.

Therefore, I changed a bit in hierarchy

```
  override func setupViews() {
    super.setupViews()

    addSubview(imgView)
    addSubview(buttonLayout)
            buttonLayout.addSubview(editButton)
            buttonLayout.addSubview(shareButton)
   }
```

and BAM ! it worked like a charm.

In fact, I need a proper explanation about why the hierarchy impact to children view.

By the way, I think most replies here are workable solution, but I selected @DonMag as final answer, because it’s clean and clear with a cool callback to Controller.

But again, my root problem is from view hierarchy.

Comment: Why are you using addTarget instead of linking this method with event by @IBAction? Do you want to change its behavior during the app execution?

Comment: I added the views programmatically, not use storyboard

Comment: RaisedButton is the subclass of UIButton?

Comment: Hey i tested your code with UIButton instead of RaisedButton , It is working , consider changing RaisedButton with UIButton and make a test. How you will be able to locate problem,

Comment: Hi, I used https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material to make the Material design for the app. RaisedButton is an UIButton, I checked the code.

Comment: did you check your view hierarchy maybe the button is being covered up by some other view?

Comment: @DatForis, yes, you are right. I checked hierarchy of views, the hierarchy was contentView=>(imageView, buttonsView=>(holderView=>(editView))) that prevented the button's click event. Therefore, I tried to change the hierarchy contentView=>(imageView, buttonsView=>(editView)), it worked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A very reliable and flexible pattern is to assign a "Callback Closure" to your cell. Put your button action handler inside the cell, and have it "call back" to the view controller.

Here is a basic example (you should be able to implement it with your custom cell with no problem):

```
//
//  CViewWithButtonCollectionViewController.swift
//  SWTemp2
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 6/5/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 DonMag. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "ImgItemCell"

class ImgItemCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    // this will be our "call back" action
    var btnTapAction : (()->())?

    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupViews()
    }

    let editButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.backgroundColor = .white
        button.setTitle("Edit", for: .normal)
        return button
    }()

    func setupViews(){

        // add a button
        addSubview(editButton)

        editButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        editButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        // add the touchUpInside target
        editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    @objc func btnTapped() {
        print("Tapped!")

        // use our "call back" action to tell the controller the button was tapped
        btnTapAction?()
    }

}

class CViewWithButtonCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 100)
        }

    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ImgItemCell

        cell.backgroundColor = .red

        // set a "Callback Closure" in the cell
        cell.btnTapAction = {
            () in
            print("Edit tapped in cell", indexPath)
            // start your edit process here...
        }

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks you, this solution is clean and clear. Just in case, I added the root problem explanation which is hinted by @DatForis, please refer to it.

Comment: Be wary of trying to use this answer with Storyboards. IBActions are not available on init, and are only accessible on awakeFromNib

Answer (score 13):

You might want to use a tag for a simpler approach, but I always implement a delegate pattern in the case of buttons inside cells

```
protocol MyCollectionViewCellDelegate: class {
    func button(wasPressedOnCell cell: MyCollectionViewCell)
}
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    weak var delegate: MyCollectionViewCellDelegate?
    var data: String = "DATA"
    @IBAction func buttonWasPressed(sender: UIButton){
        delegate?.button(wasPressedOnCell: self)
    }

}
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "reuse", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}
extension MainViewController: MyCollectionViewCellDelegate{
    func button(wasPressedOnCell cell: MyCollectionViewCell) {
        //do what you want with the cell and data
    }
}
```

Using this method will allow you to have multiple buttons inside a cell. Use a different delegate method for each button

Answer (score 2):

I have created the same scenario. The only difference is that I have used `UIButton` instead of `RaisedButton`. And it is working perfectly fine.

1.`ImgItemCell`

```
class ImgItemCell: UICollectionViewCell
{
    //MARK: View Lifecycle Methods
    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupViews()
    }

    let editButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 50))
        button.setTitle("Edit", for: .normal)
        return button
    }()

    func setupViews()
    {
        addSubview(editButton)
    }
}
```

2.`MainController` methods

```
//MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: imgCellId, for: indexPath) as! ImgItemCell
    cell.editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}

@objc func buttonPressed()
{
    print("buttonPressed !")
}
```

Comment: There might be some issue with RaisedButton then. Check if you need to send some property or delegate of RaisedButton to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

If touch action on UIButton is not detecting.

To enable touch action on the UIButton of your Custom UICollectionCell, add the below method in your Custom UICollectionCell class.

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    var view = myButton.hitTest(myButton.convert(point, from: self), with: event)
    if view == nil {
        view = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }

    return view
}
```

Comment: It is the only solution that worked

Answer (score 1):

How your `buttonpress` method will know,you are selecting which cell button.So you can differentiate with `tag`
Add in `cellForItemAtindexPath`

```
ButtonObject.tag = indexPath.item
```

and

```
func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        print("buttonPressed ! \(sender.tag)")
    }
```

Comment: @PeterPham..So your button print or not?

Comment: Hi Shabbir, how can I call to function buttonPressed, is it in cell.editButton.addTarget?

Comment: I would rather add the method to cell object and inform the controller (if needed) by the delegate pattern.

Comment: cell.editButton.tag = indexPath.item
cell.editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

Comment: Hi Michal Cichon, can you please explain more detail your solution? I am quite new with Swift 3

Comment: @PeterPham..have you add _ sender: UIButton in your buttonPressed Method??

Answer (score 0):

```
func setupViews() {
    ...
    addSubview(editButton)
    editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
}

func buttonPressed(sender:UIButton){
    print("buttonPressed !")
}
```

Comment: @PeterPham what is raised button?

Comment: I used github.com/CosmicMind/Material to make the Material design for the app. RaisedButton is an UIButton, I checked the code