# How to check if button is clicked from XIB file in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I run into the following. I have created a custom `UIView` using XIB file. I connected a VC that inherits from `UIView` and add it to the File Owner property. Connect two buttons with `@IBOutlet` and connected both buttons to the same `@IBAction` method, that will switch the background color, to get a boolean effect. By default no button is selected.

[image]

In my `ViewController.swift` file, that is connected with a View Controller in Storyboard, I add it as subview inside my `UICollectionView` cells.

Based on my two model classes (`Messages` and `PermissionMessage`), I determine what the text of the buttons should be.

My wish is to add functions to the buttons, so when button one is clicked, it will fire function A and if button two is selected, function B.

At this point I don't know where I should do this logic, to determine which function should be fired off. Also because I can create different instances of the same `BooleanView.xib` so I can't add the functions to the file owners class of that `XIB` file, am I right?

I am trying to get the button click inside the `didSelectItemAt` method of `UICollectionView`, but I can't get access to that programmatically added custom `UIView` called `BooleanView()`.

How and what should be the correct way to add functions to each instance buttons, based on the button that is clicked?

In my example I want to determine for the current instance if the selected button is `Manual` or `GPS`. If Manual, it will do something, like print a text in my console, if GPS is selected, I would like to call the initializer for the LocationManager that I stored in a custom separate class/handler.

This function is placed inside the `cellForItemAt` method of `UICollectionView`:

```
        if message is PermissionMessage {
            let bool = BooleanView()
            bool.frame = CGRect(x: 60, y: estimatedFrame.height + 15, width: estimatedFrame.width + 15 + 8, height: bool.frame.height)

            let permissionType = (message as! PermissionMessage).getTypeOfPermission()

            switch permissionType {
            case .camera:
                print("Case: camera")

                bool.leftButton.setTitle("Yes", for: .normal)
                bool.rightButton.setTitle("No", for: .normal)
                cell.addSubview(bool)
            case .location:
                print("Case: location")

                bool.leftButton.setTitle("Manual", for: .normal)
                bool.rightButton.setTitle("GPS", for: .normal)
                cell.addSubview(bool)
            }

        }
```

Note: the `message` variable is the selected array entry of `indexPath.row`.

The custom UIView class that is added to my `BooleanView.xib`:

```
class BooleanView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var leftButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var rightButton: UIButton!

    //MARK: Initialization
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // Load the nib named 'CardView' into memory, finding it in the main bundle.
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("BooleanView", owner: self, options: nil)

        self.frame = contentView.frame


        addSubview(contentView)

        // Style the custom view
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        leftButton.layer.cornerRadius = (leftButton.frame.height / 2)
        rightButton.layer.cornerRadius = (rightButton.frame.height / 2)

    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

    }

    @IBAction func pressedButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if sender.backgroundColor == Constants.BOOL_BUTTON.enabled {
            return
        }

        sender.backgroundColor = Constants.BOOL_BUTTON.enabled
        sender.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Constants.FONTS.bold, size: (sender.titleLabel?.font.pointSize)!)

        if sender.tag == 0 {
            self.rightButton.backgroundColor = Constants.BOOL_BUTTON.disabled
            self.rightButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Constants.FONTS.regular, size: (self.rightButton.titleLabel?.font.pointSize)!)
        } else {
            self.leftButton.backgroundColor = Constants.BOOL_BUTTON.disabled
            self.leftButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Constants.FONTS.regular, size: (self.leftButton.titleLabel?.font.pointSize)!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3- How to get button in UICollectionViewCell work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44368515/swift-3-how-to-get-button-in-uicollectionviewcell-work)

Comment: You need a collection view cell subclass to get info between the view controller and the bool view. I'd add a state enum of some sort to the bool view and mirror it in the cell.

Comment: Can you give me an example? @theMikeSwan. I looked at the possible duplicated post, and tried to get it work with a delegate protocol, but I think this is not working within a custom UIView class that I create based on a XIB file..

Comment: @Caspert - is the code you posted in your question working now? That is, it sets the fonts and colors correctly? And what you need is a way to tell the  view controller that the button was tapped?

Answer (score 0):

First you need a way to communicate which, if either, button has been pressed, an `enum` will work for that:

```
enum BooleanViewState {
    case none
    case left
    case right
}
```

Next your `BooleanView` needs to be able to communicate its state to interested parties. Given that you only care about the state of a given boolean view at specific moments in time the easiest is to use a computed property. Also, your current method of reaching into the view to set button titles isn't the best of practices so we will add an alternative to that as well:

```
class BooleanView: UIView {
    var boolViewState: BooleanViewState {
        get {
            if leftButton.backgroundColor == Constants.BOOL_BUTTON.enabled {
                return .left
            } else if rightButton.backgroundColor == Constants.BOOL_BUTTON.enabled {
                return .right
            } else {
                return .none
            }
        }
    }

    var buttonTitles = (leftTitle: "", rightTitle: "") {
        didSet {
            leftButton.setTitle(buttonTitles.leftTitle, for: .normal)
            rightButton.setTitle(buttonTitles.rightTitle, for: .normal)
        }
    }

    // The rest of you existing class
}
```

It is possible you will need to add a `didSet` to the outlets for the two buttons that gets the titles. The titles *might* get set before the buttons exist.

Next you need to switch from using a default `UICollectionViewCell` to a custom subclass that can hold a `BooleanView` and pass things back and forth:

```
class BooleanViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet private var boolView: BooleanView!

    var boolViewState: BooleanViewState {
        get {
            return boolView.boolViewState
        }
    }
    var buttonTitles = (leftTitle: "", rightTitle: "") {
        didSet {
            boolView.buttonTitles = buttonTitles
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to change some code in your `cellForItemAt` method

```
    if message is PermissionMessage {
        let permissionType = (message as! PermissionMessage).getTypeOfPermission()

        switch permissionType {
        case .camera:
            print("Case: camera")

            cell.buttonTitles = (leftTitle: "Yes", rightTitle: "No")
        case .location:
            print("Case: location")

            cell.buttonTitles = (leftTitle: "Manual", rightTitle: "GPS")
        }
    }
```

The last thing to do is read `boolState` from the cell in `didSelectItemAt`

```
guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? BooleanViewCell else { return }
let theState = cell.boolState
// React to the state as needed
```

This does mean that you will need to add a generic `UIView` to your prototype collection view cell in the storyboard, set its class to `BooleanView` and connect it to the outlet in `BooleanViewCell`.

That should take care of it all for you though I did all of this with no compiler so I make no guarantees I haven't mistyped or missed something all together.