# How to set Action for Buttons to every cell which will be created dynamically when user Enter a text (Swift 4)?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, collectionview

I am creating an app which will have collection view and the items to the collection view cell will be added by user dynamically.

I have created a collection view and added codes which will let the user enter input via UIalert action controllers and the item is getting added to the collection view.

The problem is, The items are not clickable, what to do to make it clickable and upon clicked it should update the table view in the same page based on selection.

Sorry, I am totally new to IOS development .

Comment: Can you post some code, it will be more clear that way

Comment: Handle action of button in cell, using delegate or block for cell to apply new added data in ViewController

Comment: I am getting formatting error when pasting code here. I have created a simple collection view with a add button where user can add name in text field and it will be added to the end of collection view using append. I am able to see the new items added but No buttons in collection view not clickable.

Comment: @TraiNguyen - Any example code for that? please

Comment: @vijaybalaji try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44371262/3146021)

Answer (score 2):

first add the button in cell file and code in cellforrowAt

```
    cell.button.tag = indexpath.row
```

then make that button's clickevent

```
cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector (property(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

the function which call on click

```
    func property(sender : UIbutton){
  //write code here and make sure to use specific indexpath use sender

}
```

Comment: I have created the button in a separate file for the collection view cell. Hence its unable to recognise the button in my view controller. Also it says error " Use of unresolved identifier 'property'" 

Though I have created a function on the same name specified inside the same file.

Answer (score 2):

There is a method called didSelectItemAtIndexPat(), refer to the documentation here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618032-collectionview?language=swift, which can be used to select any item at a specific index path.
You can write your code here to make changes those items clickable.

For updating the tableView, you will need to use delegate in order to pass information from your tableView to your viewController.